# lmerTest in R versus lme in statsmodels/Python

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, lmertest

I do have a complex linear mixed effect model.

```
model_lme = MixedLM.from_formula("Ratings ~ LCDev455*ST0LT1*TargetType*Female0Male1", groups=data["ResponseID"], data=data)
model_lme = model_lme.fit()
model_lme.summary()
```

This perfectly works in R, lmerTest. Not even a convergence warning. But in python statsmodels, it gives the error: Singular matrix.

I thought that these two packages (lmerTest in R, lme in Python) were giving the same output.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen? I am more of a beginner so I cannot really simulate my data here.

Thank you!

Comment: In the absence of a reproducible example we probably can't answer this question. Is there any chance you can share your data?

Comment: Ok, you are right, it is a research data and I am not sure if i am allowed to upload it now. I will try to find out how to create a similar dataset.

Comment: Did you check whether the R version doesn't drop automatically some variables or imposes some restrictions to make the model estimable?